# Adding oAuth to Existing ASP.NET MVC 4 Site With Existing Membership Database

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Running Visual Studio 2012 - I've looked at the new oAuth template and the default database it creates when you first run the site.

Anyone know of a tutorial on how to integrate all of these oAuth pieces into an existing MVC 4 site that already is using the Membership provider/database?

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of sites that discuss writing custom membership providers that you can connect to an existing database.

For example the ones below:

[how-do-i-setup-a-membership-provider-in-my-existing-database-using-asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121741/how-do-i-setup-a-membership-provider-in-my-existing-database-using-asp-net-mvc)

[Using ASP.NET Membership Provider with an existing user database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197337/using-asp-net-membership-provider-with-an-existing-user-database)

[How do I setup a Membership Provider in my existing database using ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121741/how-do-i-setup-a-membership-provider-in-my-existing-database-using-asp-net-mvc)

Hope these links are helpful.

Comment: None of these says anything about **oauth**